# '&' requires l-value error with getTranslation() function in Opengl

Tags: c++, c, opengl, pointers, graphics

I get the following error: *error C2102: '&' requires l-value* when compiling the following line:

```
  if (&(obj->getTranslation()).y ==5)
```

I am trying to get the y-axis coordinate of an object, but I seem to be missing something. Could you please help me out.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with the `&`? And you're comparing it to `5`? Did you intend to use `*` instead?

Comment: Why are you using `&`? What type does `getTranslation()` return?

Comment: What's the intention of the `&` in the first place? Looks dubious.

Comment: Try `if (obj->getTranslation().y == 5)` maybe...

Comment: The error is explicitly complaining about the `&`.  Can you tell us what you were hoping to get from using that `&`?  It may clear up the confusion you're having.

Comment: the object is declared as Object* obj;

Comment: We didn't ask what type `obj` is, we asked what type `getTranslation()` returns. ;-]

Comment: it returns a 3D Vector(GLfloat x, y, z;)..sorry for the ambiguity, I was under the impression that getTranslation() was an inbuilt function

Comment: `3D Vector(GLfloat x, y, z;)` is not a type. What is the _real_ type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pretty sure you just want this:

```
if (obj->getTranslation().y ==5)
```

If get Translation returns a pointer then you'll want to dereference it, so you may have been looking for:

```
if ((*obj->getTranslation()).y ==5)
```

But you could just use the dereference operator you're using on obj:

```
if (obj->getTranslation()->y ==5)
```

Comment: In your second example, you are dereferencing `y`, not the result of `getTranslation()`.

Comment: I've edited it to correct the parentheses location.  (As a historical note, the erroneous version was `*(obj-getTranslation()).y`, which as Benjamin Lindley notes, applies the `*` operator after the `.` operator.)

Comment: I believe this is the closest to the correct answer. I managed to make it work like this:    if ((&(obj->getTranslation()))->y == 5 )

Comment: @biggdman : That is beyond convoluted; if you posted the _actual, exact_ type that `getTranslation()` returns I'm sure we could tell you how to do it more clearly/succinctly.

Comment: @biggdman: That is exactly the same as `(obj->getTranslation().y == 5)`